# Are uncountable nouns altogether plural?

Tags: grammar

When multiple uncountable nouns form a single noun phrase, should it be considered to be plural?

> 1. Knowledge *and* experience **was** the only **thing** he wanted.
> 2. Knowledge *and* experience **were** the only **things** he wanted.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider these to be two items then use the plural. This would be my choice in most situations, whether the items in the list are plural or not.

There few situations where you might use "is" when considering "knowledge and experience" as one thing.

Quotes:

> In conclusion, [knowledge and experience are](https://scholarblogs.emory.edu/basicproblems002/2015/01/21/knowledge-vs-experience-which-of-these-is-education/) two different perceptions
>
> Knowledge and experience are regarded as the most important assets for sustainable success in today's knowledge-based economy.knowledge and experience is
>
> Knowledge is power, but [knowledge and experience is](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/knowledge-power-experience-powerful-robbie-naish-robbie/) powerful.

In the last example, the author uses "is" because he wants to consider "knowledge and experience" as a single property that you may have. That is rarer

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The conjucnction "and" makes the noun phrase plural despite the uncountable nature of both nouns.  The reason is that, thanks to the "and" you have at least two.